# Wildfly 8.2 fails scanning entities inside WEB-INF/lib/*.jar directory. Is this the expected behavior?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-8

I was deploying a war that contained the entities inside the `WEB-INF/classes` directory, but now I moved those entities to a separate proyect/module and now the entities reside inside `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar`

After the change wildfly failed to scan the entities producing errors while deploying.

I then tried adding

```
<class>class.inside.webinf.lib.Entity1</class>
```

tags inside my persistence.xml file and everything deployed correctly.

Full `persistence.xml` at `file.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="pu" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:/jboss/datasources/sgsdscore</jta-data-source>

      <class>io.ingenia.sgsds.score.entity.Entity1</class>
      <class>io.ingenia.sgsds.score.entity.EntityN</class>

      <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> 
      <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
         <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="200"/> 
         <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
         <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />

         <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Am I missing something ?

EJBs inside `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` where successfuly scanned though...

Comment: Asked in wildfly forums too https://developer.jboss.org/message/920231#920231

Comment: Where is your persistence.xml file in the deployment?

Comment: Question updated to answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that this answer also answers my question https://stackoverflow.com/a/6263592/39998

It's fine to have the entities inside the lib directory like `WEB-INF/lib/entities.jar`, but then the persistence.xml file must be inside `WEB-INF/lib/entities.jar/META-INF/persistence.xml`

If the persistence.xml file is inside `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml` then the automatic scanning will occurr only inside `WEB-INF/classes/*`

Makes sense. (kind of...)

Answer (score 1):

In general, this should work. I'm using JPA entity classes from a `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` in most of my projects.

However, there may be issues when some of your classes are not in the same JAR as the `persistence.xml` descriptor.

Comment: and by `there may be issues` you mean?

Comment: by the way, where should the persistence.xml be ? read the comment of my question please

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing your `persistence.xml` file.  You can specify `exclude-unlisted-classes` which will say only look at the listed classes.  You must use `jar-file` to indicate what JAR files to scan (it's not clear from your question if you're already doing that.

Comment: I put my persistence.xml in the question now. I know about 'eclude-unlisted-classes', I didn't know about 'jar-file' can you elaborate ? And then, By the spec, shouln't it scall all the classes and lib directory of 'WEB-INF' ?

Comment: EJB and JPA are two different specs, with their own rules.  You may want to review section 8.2.1.6 of the JPA spec to clarify how entities are found.  By default, they're only scanned in the root of where the persistence unit is defined.  for your use case, `jar-file` is the right thing to use.